# Node.js Express API doesn't send headers if its docker image is deployed

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, api, express

I've built an Node.js Express API where whenever the user uses the (POST) /login, if logged successfully, the api will set the Authorization Token such as this:

```
  @Post('/login')
  @UseBefore(validationMiddleware(LoginUserDto, 'body'))
  async logIn(@Res() res: Response, @Body() userData: LoginUserDto) {
    const { cookie, user } = await this.authService.login(userData);
    res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', [cookie]);
    return user
  }
```

Whenever I run the docker image locally, if it was requested by a React app it would create the token as a cookie in the browser successfully.

Since it was working, I deployed in docker image of the API in Azure and Digitalocean (in order to see if would work on both. But when I tried to login with the deployed API, it would POST with success but the cookie wouldn't be set in the browser when using the React App (in the app the credentials were set to true in order to save).

I tried to call the deployed API with Postman and Insomnia and both would save the cookie from the successful login.

With this last experiment I was really confused because the API works as expected both in postman and in the react app when run locally, but when deployed only works as expected in postman and not in React. I can't understand if the problem is from react or from the API.

I have also tried using RTK and Axios in react and both got the same results.
In the CORS options from the API the origin is set to "*"

Comment: I you list the HTTP headers sent by your server with `curl -I -X POST https://<MY_AZURE_DOMAIN>/login` do you see the line `Set-Cookie: <MY_COOKIE>`?

Comment: @MartinTovmassian I do get a 'set-cookie' value in both the response from the local hosted and deployed API when I use that command and when I request by browser or by postman. This means the error is probably in React?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already found out, seems like when creating the cookie I was not setting the Same-Site property and by default was Lax, which didn't let the browser save the cookie. I set it to none and needed to put *secure* after it.

```
public createCookie(tokenData: TokenData): string {
    return `Authorization=${tokenData.token}; HttpOnly; Max-Age=${tokenData.expiresIn}; SameSite=None; Secure`;
  }
```